# How do you create squared big pixel texture like this in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

How do you create squared big pixel texture like this in photoshop?

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? What exactly do you mean by big pixel texture ?

Comment: By "big pixel" I meant squares you can see on the image

Answer (score 2):

Hard to be certain what you're looking for; one way to get something like this would be to use the **Texture > Patchwork** filter, with *relief* set to 0, *square size* to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a grid is constructed using shape tools, then various fills, textures and filters are used to create the look thats desired, then it is probably fiddled with so that it is perfectly tile-able - using the offset filter